# Javascript - Get Select(Value) to evaluate

Tags: javascript, forms, select, getelementbyid

There are 10 different pins that I need the status for.

```
<select>
   <option value="on" id="p1StatusOn" name="pin1Status">on</option>
   <option value="off" id="p1StatusOff" name="pin1Status">off</option>
</select>
```

Javascript - Trying to get the value of pin 1-10 into an array to evaluate later to see if enabled or disabled

```
var e = [];
   for (var i=1;i<=10;i++){
       e[i] = document.getElementById("p" + i + "_status");
   }
```

Then once the I get the value, I can run validation scripts on the other inputs.

I have tried to ask this earlier, however I was quite far off the mark with what I was really trying to do. I am just learning Javascript and have been trying to figure out this issue for the majority of the day. Thank you!

Comment: Ask what?  There is no question here.  Also, you can't have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: You can not have same ID for two different controls.

Comment: please use different IDs for each element and put your question in.

Comment: I thought since only one was selected but alright that issue is understood. How can I get the value of that when I do change the ID's though? That still is the question.

Answer (score 0):

well, you are getting `p1_status` when your id is actually `p1Status`... and that's just the element, you seem to want the selected item?

Try this:

```
<select id="p1Status" name="pin1Status">
   <option value="on">on</option>
   <option value="off">off</option>
</select>
```

js

```
var e = [];
for (var i=1;i<=10;i++){
       e[i] = document.getElementById("p" + i + "Status").value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different ids for each element and also correct the getElementById parameter. To get the value you need to add .value :

```
var e = [];
       for (var i=1;i<=10;i++){
           e[i] = document.getElementById("p" + i + "Status").value;
       }
```

Comment: It's not the case of Status that's the issue, this is an example of what I am doing.

Comment: So this wouldn't be an option? I can use this for getting the value directly from the select if I feed the id of select right?

Comment: Yes is an option @Caswell . I edited it after Dennis comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably target the select, and get the selected value:

```
<select id="p1Status" name="pin1Status" class="elementToGet">
   <option value="on">on</option>
   <option value="off">off</option>
</select>
```

-

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('elementToGet'),
    e     = [];
for (var i=0; i < elems.length ;i++){
    e.push( elems[i].value );
}
```

I like actually selecting elements based on selectors like classes, and not some random numbers.

Comment: `+1` Perfect solution, [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/Ndp8G/) for that.

Comment: Do you have to use a push to get the value?

Comment: No, `push()` pushes values to an array.

Comment: Yeah I get that, what would 

    e[i] = elems[i].value;

do?

Comment: The same thing, but now would you set the indices specifically to a number, while push() just pushes to the array in the order it's executed, which in this case would be the same as setting the index, and since there really are'nt associative arrays in javascript, using the push() method is what I'd do!

Comment: Also I guess it doesn't matter in the end because the first will still be e[0] either way, however I heard that push uses a lot of overhead and is bad to use at times?

Comment: There's an old [perf here](http://jsperf.com/arraypushvsbrackets), and you can execute the bracket notation style around 79000 times every second, while push() is a little slower, and you could run push() 76000 times every second. I'll give you my scout's honour you'll never notice the difference.